# Does writing JavaScript in <script></script> tags inside a PHP file make it more secure?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Suppose I have an MVC structure. Does writing JavaScript in script tags inside a PHP view file make the code more secured?
Will it still be seen by the client in source code? 
Will there be any issues because of this?
I have tried calling an Ajax in a PHP view, but my teacher told me not to do it. I thought the only reason why she told me not to do it was the code not to get too mixed up and unreadable. Please tell me about this topic.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client, not the server (unless you use node.js instead of PHP). Putting the JS in a PHP script doesn't change that, it's still sent to the client for execution.

Comment: If the client couldn't see the Javascript then it wouldn't work. So it makes no difference, but you should keep your JS separate for purposes of organization and keeping code easy to read and maintain.

Comment: You could easily have tested this yourself. It's not more than a few minutes work to try it.

Comment: _I have tried calling an Ajax in a PHP view, but my teacher told me not to do it_... This is kind of "vague". Calling an ajax in a php view means that you have a javascript script calling a php script. There is "nothing" wrong with that, unless the design behind both javascript and php is terrible, but it's not really related to security at all. Since javascript is a client-side language, you **can't** secure it. You can obfuscate it and optimize it, but writing script tags inside a php file definitely doesn't make the script more secure.

Comment: I think the real question is why do you want to make your code "secure". If there are things inside your JS code that are private and you don't want users being able to access, then it just shouldent be there. In any case, your teacher is correct, keeping your front end seperate from your back end is a good habit to get into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php will generate page with your script tag and send it to browser - so it is not more secure. However if you move your JS code into separate file and link it in your page, the code will be more readable and easier to develop in future.

Answer (score 2):

**Code executed in the client** (browser, frontend, *whatever*) **will always be accesible** thus not "hidden" nor "secure".

Code executed in the server (backend) *may* not be visible to the client (this depends on how you structure your code, how much secure it its, etc.).